# Swap Value every time button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create simple button which will swap string value everytime its get clicked. Here are my aspx and aspx.cs file.
Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="switch.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
         <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Switch" Text="Switch" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
     </div>
     Translator From :<asp:Label runat="server" ID="testing"></asp:Label> 
     Translator To :<asp:Label runat="server" ID="testing1"></asp:Label> 
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public void SwapStrings(ref string s1, ref string s2)
    // The string parameter is passed by reference.
    // Any changes on parameters will affect the original variables.
    {
        string temp = s1;
        s1 = s2;
        s2 = temp;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Inside the method: {0} {1}", s1, s2);
        testing.Text = s1;
        testing1.Text = s2;
    }

    public void Switch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str1 = "en";
        string str2 = "ja";
        System.Console.WriteLine("Inside Main, before swapping: {0} {1}", str1, str2);

        SwapStrings(ref str1, ref str2);
    }
}
```

All I want to do is everytime i click the button, the value for "from" and "to" swapped. However the code now is only effect on the first click. I think the code must have some kind of memory to be able to save the last value. Can anybody help with the code?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are always starting with the same `str1` and `str2` values. You need to get the current label values instead of the fixed ones.

Try changing it to this in the `Swicth` method:

```
string str1 = testing.Text;
string str2 = testing1.Text;
```

On a side note there is no point in passing by reference in this case, you are not doing anything with the original variables after he method call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. Then how about the initial value? I want the first value from="en" and to="ja". Then swap everytime button clicked

Comment: Just set those as the defaults directly in the aspx file: `<asp:Label runat="server" ID="testing">en</asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1):

Use page load for set default values and check ispostback when you hit the swtch button then switch the values;

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                testing.Text = "en";
                testing1.Text = "ja";
            }

        }

        protected void Switch(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tempLanguage = testing1.Text;

            testing1.Text = testing.Text;
            testing.Text = tempLanguage;

        }
    }
```